# Вывод переменных в адресную строку

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

**Есть база данных** ,есть два пока что пустых файла **plc_user1.php и plc_user2.php** 
Для первого файла можно только использовать из базы данных *USER (1,1)* и *VAR (X1,X2)* 
для второго файла (**plc_user2.php**) соответственно *USER (2,2)* и *VAR (X1,X2)* .

*И как можно реализовать чтоб в строке состояния выводило примерно так ?*

*То есть если выбираем USER-1 , VAR-X2 , то должно быть значение  VAL-11 (как пример) ,
если выбираем USER-2 , VAR-X2 , то должно быть значение  VAL-22*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**БАЗА ДАННЫХ**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для начала не путайте __базу данных__ и __таблицу__.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прежде всего Вам необходимо в базе данных `X` использовать одинаковый. к примеру `x`.

Вот пример запроса и реализации(Обратите внимание на комментарии):

```php
<?php
// Файл первый - plc_user1.php, который работает только с user-1
?>
<div>User-1</div>
<form method="post">
    <select name="sel" required>
        <option></option>
        <option value="x1">VAR x1</option>
        <option value="x2">VAR x2</option>
    </select>
    <button formmethod="post" name="but">Отправить</button>
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['sel'])){ // Если получено значение
    $var = $_POST['sel']; // сохраняем в переменную
    if($var != null) { // Если оно не равно null (Можно заменить на !empty или if($var)

        //Раздел подключения к БД лучше вынести в отельный файл и подключать тут через `require`.
        // YourDB - название базы данных
        // YourHost - ip адрес базы данных
        // YourName - имя пользователя mysql
        // YourPass - пароль пользователя mysql
        try {
            $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=YourDB;host=YourHost', 'YourName', 'YourPass');
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

        // table - название Вашей таблицы
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `bz` WHERE `USER` = '1' AND `VAR` = :var"; // Для второго файла - значение USER = 2

        $req = $dbh->prepare($sql);

        $req->bindValue(':var', $var, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $req->execute();
        $array = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        print_r($array['VAL']); // Получаем значение VAL которое можем выводить или передавать куда угодно.

        $GetParam = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'?VAL='.$array['VAL']; // Ставим var и $array['VAR'] Если надо как в примере, но не понятна суть передачи var через GET
        header("Location: $GetParam"); // Вывод в адресную строку параметра.
    }
}
```

Тоже самое для второго файла, с соответствующими данными.

Comment: Спасибо огромное . Пример помог )